# When can you start Chazarat Hashas?

Tags: tefilla, chazarat-hashatz

How many people are needed to start Chazarat Hashas?
What about if it's time sensitive, such as people need to go, or there's danger?

Nusach: Ashkinaz

Davening: Weekday Shacharit

People at minyan: 10

So far I've gathered lechatchela - 10
If time sensitive then you can start with 8 (Pinenei Halacha)

Comment: Seemingly just the Chazan starts it. And seemingly a Minyan is needed in the vicinity. Can you clarify what else you are unsure about? Have you done any research about this? What did you find? Are there opinions you've heard about before? Why do you suspect time sensitive cases would be different?

Comment: If it's a Pikuach Nefesh situation, you can dispense with the Chazara. Saving lives is more important.

Comment: May be good to separate, 1.- how many... 2.- Are persons in duty to wait... what situations... Is there situations in which Chazara need less people bediavad?

Comment: Also may be worth addressing if this is different for, say, Yom Kippur

Comment: @SAH or mussaf of Yom Kippur, good!!!

Comment: @DoubleAA you mean Shas Gmara or Shas mishna or nusah Tunis, in this way a double s, "ss" may be a good phonetic צ

Comment: @kouty Standard Mizrahi Hebrew even within the last century pronounced צ like S, not just the Tunisians. Israeli Hebrew teachers 100 years ago used to complain that Sefardi students would often spell סדיק and בסל instead of צדיק and בצל. It's only in the last few decades that people think Sefardim have ever had a "ts" sound. We'd be better off if we stopped calling Modern Hebrew "Sefaradit" when it's not.

Comment: @DoubleAA ++ I understand. It is often dependent where you are. In Isrrael, when a Chasid ask for a street, he says rechov raavad, not RaEvEd, even if he is speaking with an other Chassid.

Comment: @huddie96 What does the word "Ashkinaz" at the end of the post indicate? Please write in full sentences and be clear what you seek. Otherwise, we don't know how to help you, and some of the volunteers here may end up wasting there time finding information you aren't seeking. Please [edit] to fix up this post.

Answer (score 1):

The שולחן ערוך seems to contradict himself in this area. In או''ח סימן נה סעיף ו he says that it is ok to say קדיש whilst someone there is sleeping or saying שמונה עשרה and there are only 10 people in the room including that person. However, in סימן קכד סעיף ד he says that if there aren't 9 people responding to חזרת הש''ץ, it is almost a ברכה לבטלה. I am aware of three approaches to this issue.

1. The דרישה in קכד,א says that the שולחן ערוך says **almost** for a reason.  Less than 9 answering should be avoided but is OK. He also brings a proof from the הלכה in סימן נה סעיף ב that you can continue דברים שבקדושה when people walk out in the middle and you are left without a מנין. Based on that proof, he would be ok with any more than 6 people including חזן.
2. מגן אברהם in סימן נה סעיף קטן ח says that we are not נוהג like the שולחן ערוך says in סימן קכד. He doesn't exactly answer for the contradiction we had but gives a פסק. Notably, he adds that מהר''ל אבן חביב was ok with any more than 6 including the חזן for חזרת הש''ץ but the מגן אברהם himself doesn't like it  and says you need 9 including חזן.
3. The שולחן ערוך הרב in סימן נה סעיף ז says that there is no contradiction because for חזרת הש''ץ you need 10 but only for קדיש and other דברים שבקדושה is less ok.

So there are a range of views. If no time pressure, wait for 10. If there is pressure, you can probably be מיקל for 6 people, but ask a Rabbi.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67888